# Dev Express Gridview checkbox

Tags: checkbox, datagrid, devexpress

Greeting,

I have problem about Dev Express in VB.NET 2005.
Im using Data Grid View.

How to use Data grid with checkbox in each row like this picture below ?

I can not find that properties.

This is regular List View in VB.NET
http://i293.photobucket.com/albums/mm54/davisvee/Snap1_zps07f5a11a.jpg

Thanks for reading and answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here you can see an example how to do this  [implement multi row selection](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#silverlight/CustomDocument5442): or here 
[use unbound checkbox column](http://www1.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E990?currentProgrammingLanguage=VB.NET)

Hope it helps. Just skip the part with selection

Comment: thanks for helping.....

I trying many things and this is the near solution

        Dim a As RepositoryItem
        a = New RepositoryItemCheckEdit()
        gridvwViewer.Columns(0).ColumnEdit = a

and the new problem is come out :
I can not tick that checkbox
http://i293.photobucket.com/albums/mm54/davisvee/Snap1_zps5898a9c1.jpg

Comment: what do you want your checkboxes to do?

Comment: I want to checked it with mouse when debug,but i dont know that code.

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you want to achieve. At this moment, you have not implement anything to those checkboxes, you just set the type of the column.  it depends on what you need to do those checkboxes. on devexpress site you find a lot of examples and also you can ask.

Comment: i just initialize that column,and i need to tick that checkbox when debug start.
but the problem is : i can not tick that checkbox when debugging.
Do u know about my problem ?

After that program will be search for all checkbox.checked = true to save in database

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your field of the dev express grid with the column of the data table your `gridview` is bound to and make sure that the case of both datatable filed and gridcolumn. Fieldname is same. After doing this thing, you need to add the following code snippet to make

```
RepositoryItemCheckEdit repositoryCheckEdit1 = gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add("CheckEdit") as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;
repositoryCheckEdit1.ValueChecked = "True";
repositoryCheckEdit1.ValueUnchecked = "False";
gridView1.Columns["Item"].ColumnEdit = repositoryCheckEdit1;
```

The above example is true for the fields which has true or false as saved values in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the selection mode as CheckBoxes, then try this in the Designer:

[image: MultiSelectMode]

Then you can get the selected row's values as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Use RepositoryItemCheckEdit from repository section, set values check as 1  and uncheckvalues as 0
and set repository to column edit 
[image: properties of repository]

Comment: this is repository, instead of using gridview properties we using repository.. feel free to use